# Why a do while loop excecutes after brake?

Tags: c++, break, do-while

I ran into strange situation here is what happens. I am using a `do while` loop and it exceutes a while function one more time after brake. 
Here is a simplyfied version of what happens:

```
int i = 0;
do{
if(i>=1) break;
}while(i++);
```

And after this `i` value is 2. I am just curious if that is how it should be or I just made an error somewhere in my more copmlex version of this code? 
This is an easy fix for this I just have to assign a to say an `iTemp` variable in the begining of the wgile and use that insted of `i`.

P.S. I was using two `do while` loops one inside of another maybe that is what caused it?

EDIT: Cmon people give me a break it was typo. :D

Comment: that code actually compiles???

Comment: You mention two things not present in your example (not including valid c++ code): More complexity, and nested loops. Can you reproduce the problem with (a fixed version of) the fragment you've provided here? If not, what do you have to add to reproduce it? Answer those questions and you're on your way.

Comment: If it was  break then there isnt any prob. when i becomes 1 it exit

Comment: you said you have two loops. cant you show code of them both?

Comment: correct your questions title too

Comment: If it was a typo, better use copy+paste next time. You never know if there is something you didn't realise. Even gurus have brainfarts sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. I was using two do while loops one inside of another maybe that is what caused it?

It could well be. A `break` (note the spelling) will only break out of *one* loop, so if it was inside the inner loop, it would break out of that loop, but continue execution immediately after the end of the inner loop. In the (fairly common) case of the outer loop ending immediately after the inner, you'd end up executing the condition of the outer loop again.

Answer (score 4):

`brake` is not a keyword and your modified version does not even compile. The old version is run instead, that is, without your new break.

Solution: Use `break`.

---

update:

> P.S. I was using two do while loops one inside of another maybe that is what caused it?

Yes. `break` does only break out of the innermost loop it is written in.

Btw, I realise that you displayed loop will always only run once. Your looping condition is `i++`, which increments `i` and gives you the value *before* the increment. Before your first increment, `i` is `0`, thus your looping condition is `0` upon first run, therefore, runs once.

Comment: This loop needs more downforce.

Answer (score 2):

check its `break` not `brake`?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
do
{    
 if(i>=1) 
    break;
}while(i++);
```

the looping condition and beak ing conditions are *unthinkable*. "sorry if i seem rude"